# My screen doesn't reflect the changes in my app though the setState method works well

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test, flutter-state, statefulwidget

I'm trying to call a StatefulWidget(i.e `FirstPage()`) within a MaterialApp. I'm pretty much new to flutter and I don't know where I went wrong. According to my knownledge I've used `StatefulWidget` to tell flutter my screen on that page is going to encounter some changes in UI. But I got no idea to fix this error.

---

`main.dart` file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_project/main.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: FirstPage());
  }
}

class FirstPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const FirstPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FirstPage> createState() => _FirstPageState();
}

class _FirstPageState extends State<FirstPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String buttonName = "Click";
    int currentIndex = 0;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("App title "),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: currentIndex == 0
            ? Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: double.infinity,
                color: Colors.blueAccent,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 280,
                      height: 80,
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            side: BorderSide.none,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18),
                          ),
                          backgroundColor: const Color.fromRGBO(9, 8, 99, 90),
                          foregroundColor: Colors.red,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            buttonName = "Clicked";
                            //print(buttonName0);
                          });
                        },
                        child: Text(buttonName),
                      ),
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).push(
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (BuildContext context) {
                              //'BuildContext' - datatype and 'context' - variable name
                              return const SecondPage();
                            },
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      child: const Text("Move to new page"),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            : Image.asset("images/img.png"),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(label: "Home", icon: Icon(Icons.home)),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(label: "Settings", icon: Icon(Icons.settings))
        ],
        currentIndex: currentIndex,
        onTap: (int index) {
          //index value here is returned by flutter by the function 'onTap'
          setState(() {
            currentIndex = index;
            //print(currentIndex);
          });
        },
      ),
    ); //Scaffold represents the skeleton of the app(displays white page)
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const SecondPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
    );
  }
}
```

Images:

[Before pressing `Click` and `Settings` button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rxr9a.png)

[After pressing `Click` and `Settings` looks the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWypp.png)

I want the screen to change the ElevatedButton `Click` to `Clicked` when `onPressed()` is triggered and also, the app should be able to switch `settings` page when the `onTap()` method is triggered in the bottom navigation bar.

The code worked initially when I refrained from calling an entire page of Scaffold from Material app, but as soon as I changed the part

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: FirstPage());     //<-- this part
  }
}
```

I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your variables outside the build method.Else it will reset to default on every build.
It will be like

```dart
class _FirstPageState extends State<FirstPage> {
    //here 
    String buttonName = "Click";
    int currentIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Not here
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
```

More about  [StatefulWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html)